# Combining 'var' statements

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint is throwing problems telling me to `Combine this with the previous 'var' statement` but I'm not sure how I'd do it correctly with my code:

```
var len = results.rows.length, i;
//loop around each record in the database
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var singleRecord = results.rows.item(i);

    //create list
     var individualRecord = '';
     individualRecord = '<li><a href="#info" id="anIndividualRecord" data-key="' + individualRecord.id + '" >';
```

it's telling me to combine the three `var` statements in there but if anyone could advise me as to how to do this without creating more problems, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well it doesn't make much sense to declare "individualRecord" with an initializer expression only to overwrite that value in the next statement.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I assume OP has trimmed out some code `var foo = 1; console.log(foo); var foo = 0;` logs `1`.

Comment: You set it to three different things, the second of which renders the third pretty pointless. It wasn't asking you to call them the same name, it was asking you to only use a single `var` keyword with commas between the initializations.

Comment: @PaulS. Embarrassed - I didn't consider the hoisting.

Answer (score 2):

Do it all within your top `var` declaration

```
var len = results.rows.length, i, inidividualRecord, singleRecord;

for(i=0; i< len; i++) {
  singleRecord = results.rows.item(i);

  individualRecord = '<li><a href="#info" id="anIndividualRecord" data-key="' + singleRecord.id + '" >';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining multiple `var`s from the same scope is as simple as removing the `var` statement from one line and appending the related identifiers to a different `var` in the same scope.

```
var len = results.rows.length,
    i,
    individualRecord; // added identifier, only need one var'd copy of each identifier

//loop around each record in the database
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    individualRecord = results.rows.item(i); // removed var

    //create list
     individualRecord = ''; // removed var
     individualRecord = '<li><a href="#info" id="anIndividualRecord" data-key="' + individualRecord.id + '" >';
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-declare a variable in this case you was doing that: individualRecord.
and jsHint probably is throwing that you need to combine your `var declarations` due hoisting in JavaScript.

```
(function () {
  var len = results.rows.length,
    i,
    individualRecord,
    singleRecord;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    singleRecord = results.rows.item(i);
    individualRecord = '';
    individualRecord = '<li><a href="#info" id="anIndividualRecord" data-key="' + individualRecord.id + '" >';
  }
}());
```

Comment: Yeah I accidentally mistyped a variable name in the code in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three things you can do with a variable: `Declaration`, `Initialization` and `Assignment`. The keyword `var` indicates a variable declaration, whis is only done once for each variable. This often comes together with the `Initialization`, setting the initial value of the variable. The correct way is:

```
// add individualRecord here
var len = results.rows.length, i,singleRecord, individualRecord;

//loop around each record in the database
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // omit the "var" here
    singleRecord = results.rows.item(i);

    // and here as well
     individualRecord = '';
```

Javascript does some nasty stuff called ["hoisting"](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), so it's important to know the subtle differences.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to change the name of one of the variables in my sample code, updated.

Comment: @Alan The you do the same with both variables. Because you are doing the declaration in the for loop, you are re-declaring the variables each time, which is probably not what you intended to do. I updated my answer for you.